# New Delimited File Preview error

Tags: talend

I am trying to use Talend Open Studio v5.4.1.
When I want to create a **new delimited file** metadata, I get the following message error:

> Failed to generate code.
>   Preview error. Some settings must be changed.
>   Note: Preview errors are generally due to a wrong encoding setting.
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.shadow.ShadowFilePreview.preview(ShadowFilePreview.java:90)
>   org.talend.repository.ui.utils.ShadowProcessHelper.getCsvArray(ShadowProcessHelper.java:383)
>   org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.files.delimited.DelimitedFileStep2Form$PreviewProcessor.nonUIProcessInThread(DelimitedFileStep2Form.java:1249)
>   org.talend.commons.ui.swt.thread.SWTUIThreadProcessor$1.run(SWTUIThreadProcessor.java:74)

And I know the problem is not coming from my file setting because I did the same on Talend OS v6 and it worked!
But I have to use the v5.4.1

I tried running it as an administrator but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved it. The problem is that the v.5.4.1 doesn't support the Java 1.8.
So the solution is to install the JDK/JRE 1.7 and specify the path into Talend.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was incorrect setting in Preferences/Java/Installed JRes that was the cause of the same error.
 I set JRE home to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin (wrong) instead of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121 (right)